# Proving A is a subset of S by mathematical induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, definition, recursion

Suppose I have a question similar to:

Let $S$ be defined recursively by

(1) $5 ∈ S$ and

(2) if $s ∈ S$ and $t ∈ S$, then $st ∈ S$.

Let $A = \{5^i \mid i ∈ Z+\}$. 
Prove that $A ⊆ S$ by mathematical induction.

I know for mathematical induction you need a base case and then you want to assume the hypothesis and try to show that (n+1) would also be true. Maybe the recursive definitions are throwing me off, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Did you mean to say that $s+t\in S$, not $st\in S$?

Comment: The problem I'm being asked to solve are two variables multiplying each other.

Comment: Then $S$ would only contain powers of $5$, and $A$ would not be a subset of it. For example, $10 \in A$ but not in $S$.

Comment: Is it possible you were asked to prove $A\supseteq S$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: There was a type-o with my question, I changed 5i to  5^i sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The base case is $n = 1$.  You need to prove that $5^1 \in S$.

The induction step: You need to prove that if $5^n \in S$ then $5^{n+1} \in S$.

If you do those, the it follows that all $5^n \in A$ are in S.  And therefore $A \subset S$.

Can you do these?

===

You have the rule that if $s, t \in S$ then $st \in S$.  Do you have any values  in $S$ that when multiplied together equal $5^{n+1}$?

Comment: I'm trying. So if n=1 should be our base case we have, show 5^1 ∈ S. Well, S was defined as starting out with 5 ∈ S. so 5 ∈ S. Next, assume that 5^n ∈ S is true <--(our hypothesis) show 5^n+1∈S is also true. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: You have the rule s,t $in$ S, then st $\in$ S.  Can you use that?

Comment: 5^n and 5 are both to be assumed to be in S based on our hypothesis and base case. So, if s = 5^n and t = 5, how would that show 5^n+1 is also in S?

Comment: If 5 is in S and $5^{n}$ is in S the $5*5^{n}$ is in S because of the rule about S.